# UPDATE query containing IN with subquery is very slow

Tags: mysql

I have this `UPDATE` query to change the statuses (status=1) of records in the `videos` table for all `id_video` which have a count of 10 records in the `thumbnail` table where `thubmnails.status` is 1.

The query works but its very slow due to the large size of the thumbnails table. Any suggestions on how I could improve the speed of this query?

```
UPDATE videos 
SET    videos.status = 1 
WHERE  videos.id_video IN (SELECT thumbnails.id_video 
                           FROM   thumbnails 
                           WHERE  thumbnails.status = 1 
                           GROUP  BY thumbnails.id_video 
                           HAVING Count(thumbnails.id_thumbnail) = 10) 
       AND videos.status = 2;
```

Indexes are set for id_video in both tables & id_thumbnail for thumbnails table. And also indexes for `status` columns.

Comment: How about adding an index on `thumbnails.status` and `videos.status`

Comment: And if that does not work add the output of `explain select ...` to your question along with the table definitions.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, there are indexes on `thumbnails.status` and `videos.status`. Updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the IN clause by making your query more simple

```
UPDATE videos v
SET v.status = 1
WHERE v.status = 2 AND (
    SELECT COUNT(t.id_thumbnail)
    FROM thumbnails t
    WHERE t.id_video = v.id_video AND t.status = 1
) = 10;
```

Videos v records only get updated when they have status 2 and than they have a count of 10 thumbnails t with the video id of v and status 1.

Answer (score 0):

What if you convert that `IN` clause to a `JOIN` condition like

```
UPDATE videos v
JOIN (SELECT thumbnails.id_video 
                           FROM   thumbnails 
                           WHERE  thumbnails.status = 1 
                           GROUP  BY thumbnails.id_video 
                           HAVING Count(thumbnails.id_thumbnail) = 10) xxx
ON v.id_video = xxx.id_video
SET v.status = 1 
WHERE v.status = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using EXISTS instead of IN:

```
UPDATE videos 
SET    videos.status = 1 
WHERE  videos.status = 2
AND EXISTS (SELECT thumbnails.id_video 
            FROM   thumbnails 
            WHERE  thumbnails.status = 1 
            GROUP  BY thumbnails.id_video 
            HAVING Count(thumbnails.id_thumbnail) = 10
            AND thumbnails.id_video = videos.id_video);
```